# how to parse url from iframe code in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, iframe

I have a youtube iframe code.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zfpmc-NnjXQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can i print only url from that iframe code in angular.

Please help.

Comment: I'm afraid we need more context and explanation. Is this iframe already in your view? If it is in your view, then you already have the URL. If it's not, then where is it? Also what do you mean `print only url`? Please take time to write a proper question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

In ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Set iframe source';
  url: string = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/zfpmc-NnjXQ";
  urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.urlSafe= this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
 }
}
```

In html file:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
 <div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>Reports</h1>
 </div>

<iframe width="560" height="315" frameBorder="0" [src]="urlSafe"></iframe>
```

For more details: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how can i seperate url from iframe dynamically?

Comment: What do you really mean? Please be clearer.